# Bluetooth broken on Android ROM (LineageOS 16)

Tags: android, bluetooth, camera, cyanogenmod, rom

I want to build a custom (unofficial) version of `LineageOS 16.0` for my `Sony Xperia ZL (C6506)`. I managed to actually get the ROM to build using the device tree and various files from the GitHub repository `fusion3-common`. However, after flashing the ROM, it was immediately apparent that both the Bluetooth and the camera were not working. As far as I know, every part of the ROM but those two works so far. So, I need some guidance as to how to go about fixing the bluetooth/camera issues. When I boot the ROM, a message appears every 1-2 seconds notifying me that "Bluetooth has stopped". This continues forever and gets really annoying when using the device. As expected, connections with bluetooth don't work either. As for the camera, the app just says there isn't a camera connected and quits. I suspect these issues are caused by incompatible vendor binaries.

Here is part of the logcat:

```
11-20 12:15:47.919 32620 32662 I bt_hci  : hci_initialize
11-20 12:15:47.922   215   215 W hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0::IBluetoothHci/default in either framework or device manifest.
11-20 12:15:47.923 32620 32642 D bt_hci  : hci_module_start_up starting async portion
11-20 12:15:47.926 32620 32662 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
11-20 12:15:47.942 32620 32662 I bt_hci  : hci_initialize: IBluetoothHci::getService() returned 0xa7a6f140 (local)
11-20 12:15:47.943 32620 32662 I android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: BluetoothHci::initialize()
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 D         : get_local_address: Trying /data/misc/bluetooth/bdaddr
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 D         : get_local_address: Got Factory BDA 00:eb:2d:4f:a3:b1
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: ++init
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: bt-vendor : get_bt_soc_type
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: vendor.qcom.bluetooth.soc set to smd
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: vendor.qcom.bluetooth.soc not set, so using default.
11-20 12:15:47.948 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: BD Address: b1:a3:4f:2d:eb:00
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 D android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: Open vendor library loaded
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: bt-vendor : BT_VND_OP_POWER_CTRL: On
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: bluetooth status is on
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: bt-vendor : resetting BT status
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 W bt_vendor: Hw_config: nState = 0
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 W bt_vendor: Hw_config: nState = 1
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: bluetooth status is on
11-20 12:15:47.952 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: bt-vendor : BT_VND_OP_USERIAL_OPEN
11-20 12:15:47.957 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: Done intiailizing UART
11-20 12:15:47.959 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: Done intiailizing UART
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: Bluetooth FW and transport layer are initialized
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 D android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: OnFirmwareConfigured result: 0
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 I android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: Firmware configured in 0.000s
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 I android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: OnFirmwareConfigured: lpm_timeout_ms 1000
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 I bt_vendor: __op: property_get: persist.vendor.service.bdroid.lpmcfg: all
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 D android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: low_power_mode_cb result: 0
11-20 12:15:47.960 32620 32662 D android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl: OnFirmwareConfigured Calling StartLowPowerWatchdog()
11-20 12:15:47.961 32620 32662 I bt_hci  : event_finish_startup
11-20 12:15:47.961 32620 32642 I bt_core_module: module_start_up Started module "hci_module"
11-20 12:15:47.963 32620 32665 I bt_osi_thread: run_thread: thread id 32665, thread name bt_workqueue started
11-20 12:15:47.965 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.964974:INFO:btu_task.cc(107)] Bluetooth chip preload is complete
11-20 12:15:47.967 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.967568:INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 81818181-8181-8181-8181-818181818181
11-20 12:15:47.968 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.967965:INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=1
11-20 12:15:47.968 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.968331:INFO:gatt_api.cc(161)] GATTS_AddService
11-20 12:15:47.968 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.968636:INFO:gatt_api.cc(265)] GATTS_AddService: service parsed correctly, now starting
11-20 12:15:47.969 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.969552:INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 82828282-8282-8282-8282-828282828282
11-20 12:15:47.970 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.969857:INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=2
11-20 12:15:47.970 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.970132:INFO:gatt_api.cc(161)] GATTS_AddService
11-20 12:15:47.970 32620 32665 I         : [1120/121547.970437:INFO:gatt_api.cc(265)] GATTS_AddService: service parsed correctly, now starting
11-20 12:15:47.971 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_HCI : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.971 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_L2CAP : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.971 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_RFCOMM : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.971 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_AVDT : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.971 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_AVRC : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_A2D : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_BNEP : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_BTM : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_HID_HOST : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_PAN : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_SDP : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_SMP : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_HID_DEV : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_BTAPP : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.972 32620 32665 I bt_bte  : BTE_InitTraceLevels -- TRC_BTIF : Level 2
11-20 12:15:47.974 32620 32666 I bt_osi_thread: run_thread: thread id 32666, thread name btu message loop started
11-20 12:15:47.977 32620 32667 I bt_osi_thread: run_thread: thread id 32667, thread name module_wrapper started
11-20 12:15:47.977 32620 32667 I bt_core_module: module_start_up Starting module "controller_module"
11-20 12:15:48.046 32620 32664 D bt_hci  : get_waiting_command VS event found treat it as valid 0xffff
11-20 12:15:48.047 32620 32667 E bt_hci  : read_command_complete_header: return status - 0x1
11-20 12:15:48.062 32620 32667 I bt_core_module: module_start_up Started module "controller_module"
11-20 12:15:48.062 32620 32667 W bt_osi_thread: run_thread: thread id 32667, thread name module_wrapper exited
11-20 12:15:48.064 32620 32665 W bt_btm  : btm_decode_ext_features_page: feature page 1 ignored
11-20 12:15:48.064 32620 32666 I bt_btm_sec: BTM_SecRegister p_cb_info->p_le_callback == 0x0x94c58db5
11-20 12:15:48.064 32620 32666 I bt_btm_sec: BTM_SecRegister btm_cb.api.p_le_callback = 0x0x94c58db5
11-20 12:15:48.065 32620 32666 I bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 3df51175-d5d2-6289-ebe4-b8f015f52bd9
11-20 12:15:48.065 32620 32666 I bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=3
11-20 12:15:48.091 32620 32664 D bt_hci  : get_waiting_command VS event found treat it as valid 0xffff
11-20 12:15:48.091 32620 32666 F bt_stack: [FATAL:btm_ble_gap.cc(488)] Check failed: p_vcs_cplt_params->opcode == HCI_BLE_VENDOR_CAP_OCF.
11-20 12:15:48.092 32620 32666 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 32666 (btu message loo), pid 32620 (droid.bluetooth)
11-20 12:15:48.229 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32620: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.229 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32627: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.229 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32628: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.230 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32629: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.230 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32630: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.231 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32631: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.231 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32632: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.231 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32633: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.232 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32634: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.232 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32635: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.232 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32641: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.233 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32642: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.233 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32643: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.233 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32644: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.234 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32645: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.234 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32646: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.235 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32647: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.235 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32648: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.235 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32649: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.236 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32650: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.236 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32657: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.236 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32658: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.237 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32659: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.237 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32660: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.237 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32661: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.238 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32662: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.238 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32664: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.239 32673 32673 W crash_dump32: failed to fetch registers for thread 32665: I/O error
11-20 12:15:48.275 32673 32673 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
11-20 12:15:48.277   319   319 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 32666
11-20 12:15:48.278 32673 32673 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 32620 (target tid = 32666)
11-20 12:15:48.371 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-20 12:15:48.372 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : LineageOS Version: '16.0-20181120-UNOFFICIAL-odin'
11-20 12:15:48.372 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Sony/C6503/C6503:5.1.1/10.7.A.0.228/3219080026:user/release-keys'
11-20 12:15:48.372 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
11-20 12:15:48.372 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
11-20 12:15:48.372 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : pid: 32620, tid: 32666, name: btu message loo  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
11-20 12:15:48.373 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
11-20 12:15:48.373 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : Abort message: '[FATAL:btm_ble_gap.cc(488)] Check failed: p_vcs_cplt_params->opcode == HCI_BLE_VENDOR_CAP_OCF.
11-20 12:15:48.373 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : '
11-20 12:15:48.373 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00007f9a  r2  00000006  r3  00000008
11-20 12:15:48.373 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     r4  00007f6c  r5  00007f9a  r6  936e796c  r7  0000010c
11-20 12:15:48.373 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     r8  936e79a4  r9  936e7df4  r10 936e7998  r11 936e7df0
11-20 12:15:48.374 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     ip  00000041  sp  936e7958  lr  af831065  pc  af828d8e
11-20 12:15:48.639 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :
11-20 12:15:48.639 32673 32673 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
11-20 12:15:48.639 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0001cd8e  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
11-20 12:15:48.639 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0007b5d7  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::debug::BreakDebugger()+10)
11-20 12:15:48.639 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0008b2ff  /system/lib/libchrome.so (logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+746)
11-20 12:15:48.639 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0014606f  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (btm_ble_vendor_capability_vsc_cmpl_cback(tBTM_VSC_CMPL*)+78)
11-20 12:15:48.640 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 001505f3  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (btm_vsc_complete(unsigned char*, unsigned short, unsigned short, void (*)(tBTM_VSC_CMPL*))+38)
11-20 12:15:48.640 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00160769  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (btu_hcif_command_complete_evt_on_task(BT_HDR*, void*)+440)
11-20 12:15:48.640 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0007c503  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask(char const*, base::PendingTask*)+162)
11-20 12:15:48.640 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0008e145  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::RunTask(base::PendingTask*)+324)
11-20 12:15:48.641 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0008e37b  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask(base::PendingTask)+26)
11-20 12:15:48.641 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0008e61f  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::DoWork()+218)
11-20 12:15:48.641 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0008f313  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::MessagePumpDefault::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)+98)
11-20 12:15:48.641 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0008df2f  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()+62)
11-20 12:15:48.641 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 000a1cad  /system/lib/libchrome.so (base::RunLoop::Run()+80)
11-20 12:15:48.642 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 00160c0d  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (btu_message_loop_run(void*)+188)
11-20 12:15:48.642 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 001b1181  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (work_queue_read_cb(void*)+52)
11-20 12:15:48.642 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 001afd3b  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (run_reactor(reactor_t*, int)+218)
11-20 12:15:48.642 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 001afc35  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (reactor_start(reactor_t*)+44)
11-20 12:15:48.642 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #17 pc 001b0dd3  /system/lib/libbluetooth.so (run_thread(void*)+142)
11-20 12:15:48.642 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #18 pc 00064a23  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
11-20 12:15:48.643 32673 32673 F DEBUG   :     #19 pc 0001dfa5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
11-20 12:15:49.121   319   319 E /system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_15
11-20 12:15:49.162   621   676 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_15 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
11-20 12:15:49.173   621   670 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
11-20 12:15:49.173   621   670 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
11-20 12:15:49.221   621   621 D BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothServiceConnection, disconnected:
```

I can't really fit the whole thing here, so here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/GR94xmpF

Anyways, this is my first time building an unofficial version of LineageOS, so I am not that familiar with everything. However, I am willing to do anything to get it to work. Thank you in advance for any advice :)

Comment: This is not the right place for this question , you might find some help on https://android.stackexchange.com/ , or XDA Forums

Comment: If the topic has continued/opened anew somewhere else it would be nice to post a follow up link.